# How to do jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I was following the jQuery Code but I've seemed to have messed up somewhere somehow...

```
$.ajax(url:"/contact", success:function(results){$('#wrapper').html(results)});
```

I was on the jQuery website trying to figure it out, but it seems that its overloaded!
Am I setting it up wrong, or does it require some syntax that I've missed? I saw an example of someone not chaining the jQuery call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh you have a syntax error! Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({url:"/contact", success:function(results){$('#wrapper').html(results)}});
```

Comment: Anytime, Happy Coding!